# Answer for "Which animal do you like most?"

Tags: grammar, answers

I found a question in school that is

> Which animal do you like most?

The answer is

> cat I like most.

is it true grammatically or not?

Comment: "Cat I like most" isn't a complete sentence. It's at best a noun phrase, though there should be a determiner at the start, e.g. "the cat I like most". You can say, "I like cats the most."

Comment: @Jasper Done. :)

Comment: The "default" sequence in English is [*Subject + Verb + Object*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93object), so *I like cats most* is "natural" in most contexts, whereas *Cats I like most* would be seen as an unusual (or "marked") form. But I'd say the singular *Cat I like most* is to all intents and purposes "ungrammatical".

Comment: This is something you'd hear in casual conversation and you'd be able to hear the difference in inflection. If you attempted to capture the dialogue you would need some punctuation in there as well. It's not an answer you'd write for school since it's not strictly grammatical.

Answer (score 3):

> **Sentence** *noun*
>   1 A set of words that is complete in itself, typically containing a subject and predicate, conveying a statement, question, exclamation, or command, and consisting of a main clause and sometimes one or more subordinate clauses.

"Cat I like most" isn't a complete sentence because it doesn't represent a 'complete thought'. It's at best a noun phrase, though there should be a determiner at the start, e.g. "the cat I like most".

Here's an example of a sentence that captures what I think you're trying to express:

- I like cats the most.